# Open one form and close two forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 forms

1. frmDashboard
2. frmMenu
3. frmText

In FrmDashboard

```
frmText frmtext= new frmText();
frmtext.Show();
```

In FrmText

```
this.close(); // close FrmText

frmMenu frmmenu = new frmMenu();
frmmenu.show(); // to show FrmMenu

frmDashboard frmD = new frmDashboard();
frmD.Hide(); // didn't work
frmD.dispose();// didn't work
frmD.close();// didn't work
```

Why FrmDashboard doesn't close? Please help me. I'm new C# window developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in FrmText, you are creating a new frmDashboard, but I understand that you want to close the already open instance of frmDashboard.

Add a property to frmText:

```
public frmDashboard formToClose {get; set; }
```

When creating frmText, set this property:

```
frmText frmtext= new frmText();
frmText.formToClose = this;
frmtext.Show();
```

Then, you can close it inside frmDashboard:

```
formToClose.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference to the object that is the FrmDashboard, and simply call that.close when you need to close it.

Just pass it through the constructor and keep an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass through a reference to the form to the other form like this

```
private frmDashBoard Dashboard;
public frmText(frmDashBoard dash)
{
    Dashboard = dash;
}
```

then you can just go

```
if (Dashboard != null)
    Dashboard.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things to think about:

If `frmDashboard` is the parent form of all the other forms, and you're somehow, trying to close it from another child form, it will close also all the children forms.

If you just want to hide your `frmDasboard` while the other forms are opened, you can wire up the close event of the child form, and use it to hide/show your `frmDashboard`

```
this.Hide();
var frmMenu = new frmMenu();
frmMenu.Show();
frmMenu.Closed += (formSender, formEvents) =>
{
    this.Show();
};
```